# order of assembly load

Tags: .net, assemblies

I have an assembly call it A.dll that is xcopied deployed with A.exe.  Updates to A.dll are not appearing on the server where I deploy.  It turns out an old version of A.dll has been installed to the GAC.  Indeed when I delete A.dll from my local run path A.exe still runs as it is finding the version in the GAC.

So my understanding was the .NET runtime would look in the local folder where an EXE is run for referenced assemblies.  If not found there look in the GAC.  Is this not the case?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Your experiment made it pretty clear that is not the case.  GAC is first.